# jQuery Mobile: how to click a record from a list and edit it

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery-mobile

I have 2 pages: #page_contact_list and #page_contact_edit. After clicking a contact from the list, I wish to make a transition to #page_contact_edit, load the contact data of the record I clicked and save it by clicking the save 'Save' button.

My questions are:

- Where in the list should I put the record id (mysql contacts.id), is this a special attribute, a href parameter,...
- Which event is meant to catch the contact id that I passed
- Which event should I use to make an AJAX call to load the contact data from the database and fill the form
- How should I make the 'Save' event, if successfull #page_contact_edit transits back to #page_contact_list

  ```
  <div data-role="page" id="page_contact_list">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
          <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
              Contacts
          </li>
          <li data-theme="c">
              <a href="#page_contact_edit" data-transition="slide">
                  James
              </a>
          </li>
           <li data-theme="c">
              <a href="#page_contact_edit" data-transition="slide">
                  Jenna
              </a>
          </li>
          <li data-theme="c">
              <a href="#page_contact_edit" data-transition="slide">
                  Mark
              </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="page_contact_edit">
      <div data-role="content">
          <form action="">
              <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                      <label for="textinput1">
                          Name
                      </label>
                      <input name="name" id="textinput1" value="" type="text" />
                  </fieldset>
              </div>
              <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                      <label for="textinput2">
                          Second name
                      </label>
                      <input name="second_name" id="textinput2" value="" type="text" />
                  </fieldset>
              </div>
              <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                      <label for="textinput3">
                          Phone
                      </label>
                      <input name="phone" id="textinput3" value="" type="text" />
                  </fieldset>
              </div>
              <a data-role="button" href="#page_contact_list">
                  Save
              </a>
              <a data-role="button" href="#page_contact_list">
                  Cancel
              </a>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/606/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please copy paste the contents from this url to a html file and test it locally. http://pastebin.com/LyhLrK7Q.

- Where in the list should I put the record id (mysql contacts.id), is
  this a special attribute, a href parameter --- ***you are free to use
  any attribute name prefixed by `data-` refer the sample code
  attached***
- Which event is meant to catch the contact id that I passed ---
  ***attached a click on the `li` of the listview to catch the `data-contact-id ="1"` . This is too covered in the sample.***
- Which event should I use to make an AJAX call to load the contact
  data from the database and fill the form --- ***changePage method
  should be one fine place to fetch the record using ajax. i have used
  `setTimeout` to simulate ajax. You can use this timer callback as
  your ajax callback***
- How should I make the 'Save' event, if successfull #page_contact_edit
  transits back to #page_contact_list -- ***few javascript validation
  on the edit page should be fine. I have made the transition to be in
  reverse direction once the user clicks on the cancel or save
  button.***